# Netbeans cannot find java.io.InputStream

Tags: java, netbeans, inputstream, java-io

Actually, he cannot find java.io.

It recognizes `import java.io.*;
import java.io.IOException;`

but when I try `InputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("users.xml");`, i get the following error:

> C:\Users\cpantaziu\Documents\NetBeansProjects\url\src\main\java\com\mkyong\common\controller\FailRegisterController.java:[120,12] cannot find symbol
>   symbol  : variable InputStream.

Tools -> Java Platforms ses my jdk 1.6.

Why am I getting this?

Comment: When You write code like above, netbeans does not mark it in red?

Comment: Wow, who uses NetBeans these days :)

Comment: who uses jdk 1.6? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to assign a  **reference variable**:

```
InputStream ref= this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("users.xml");
```

Answer (score 2):

You must name a variable:

```
InputStream is = this.getClas()...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

    /**
     *
     * @author mbarb
     */
    public class LoadSave {
    
        public static BufferedImage GetPlayerAtlas(){
            BufferedImage img = null;
            InputStream is = 
    LoadSave.class.getResourceAsStream("Res/player2.png");
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(is);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }//try catch .close() 
        return img;

        }
     }
```

I'm have the same issue here in the code above.

i just get this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
        at java.desktop/javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1358)
        at Utilities.LoadSave.GetPlayerAtlas(LoadSave.java:19)
        at Entities.Player.loadAnimations(Player.java:102)
        at Entities.Player.<init>(Player.java:29)
        at com.mycompany.platformgame.Game.initClasses(Game.java:32)
        at com.mycompany.platformgame.Game.<init>(Game.java:21)
        at com.mycompany.platformgame.PlatformGame.main(PlatformGame.java:7)
Command execution failed.
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33755183)